# How to Get Previous Month From Selected Month

Tags: php

My user can select a date range from input field. after that, I want to get the 
   previous month from the selected month.

```
echo $first_day_of_month = date('Y-m-d',strtotime(request()->query_date_form)).'<br/>';
echo $last_day_of_month = date('Y-m-d',strtotime(request()->query_date_to)).'<br/>';
```

now my back end get the previous month. my code is

```
echo $first_day_of_last_month =date("$first_day_of_month",strtotime('first day of last month')).'<br/>'; 
echo $last_day_of_last_month =date("$last_day_of_month",strtotime('last day of last month'));
```

But it returns me the current month again like:

```
2018-10-01
2018-10-16
2018-10-01
2018-10-16
```

please, anyone help me to get the previous month.

Comment: Why are you feeding dates in Y-m-d format to the `date` function as first parameter …?

Comment: Are you expecting `2018-09-30` & `2018-09-01` ?

Comment: @misorude, I am a novices coder. I don't know the correct format.

Comment: @JulesR yes, i want it like this format.

Comment: _“I am a novices coder. I don't know the correct format”_ - then you should still go read up on how functions are properly used in the manual, or some other resource. Passing a date in Y-m-d format as first parameter for `date` makes really no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

First day of last month

```
echo $first_day_of_last_month = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of '.date('M', strtotime(request()->query_date_form))));
```

Last day of last month

```
echo $last_day_of_last_month = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of '.date('M', strtotime(request()->query_date_to))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the last and 1st date of the last month.

```
echo $first_day_of_last_month =date("Y-m-d",strtotime($first_day_of_month.' first day of last month')).'<br/>'; 
echo $last_day_of_last_month =date("Y-m-d",strtotime($last_day_of_month.' last day of last month'));
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's return me 2018-10-01
2018-10-16
1970-01-01
1970-01-01

Comment: it means $first_day_of_month & $last_day_of_month is not getting correct value

Comment: it's return first day of 1970's first month and last day of 1970's first month. but i need 2018-09-01 and 2018-09-30

Comment: Try this
 $first_day_of_month = "2018-10-01";
$last_day_of_month = "2018-10-16";

echo $first_day_of_last_month =date("Y-m-d",strtotime($first_day_of_month.'first day of last month')).'<br/>'; 
echo $last_day_of_last_month =date("Y-m-d",strtotime($last_day_of_month.'last day of last month'));

Answer (score 0):

```
$first_day_of_month = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(request()->query_date_from));
$last_day_of_month = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(request()->query_date_to));

//first day of last month
echo $first_day_of_last_month = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($first_day_of_month . "first day of last month"));
//last day of last month
echo $last_day_of_last_month = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($last_day_of_month . "last day of last month"));
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow :). Can you add more detail to your answer, please?